# API of timezone is not working after deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, https, netlify

I have created a timeZone application project to get the time of Asian Cities like (Baku,Kabul,Tokyo,Kolkata...) based on react framework and the app gets its data from `worldtimeapi` ([example of Baku](http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Baku)) and the project was completed successfully and it was running great on my localhost and after that i created a build folder and deployed at `Netlify` hosting platform but after deploying its not working only but the same API calls and codes are been running completely successfully at my local network , serve ...
This is the deployed project : [link](https://613c3d6616b9dee9895f96c9--adoring-einstein-8cdfd1.netlify.app/)

This is the code:

##### App.js

```
import './App.css';
import TimeZoneComponent from './Timezone';

function App() {
 return (
   <div >
    <h1 style={{textAlign:'center',fontSize:'50px'}}>Time Travel</h1>
    <TimeZoneComponent />
    <h2>
      Credits: Mohit-Maroliya
    </h2>
</div>
);
}

export default App;
```

##### TimeZone.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const TimeZoneComponent = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [city, setCity] = useState("");
const [printCity, setPrintCity] = useState(false);

const handleClick = () => {
  setPrintCity(true);
  if (printCity) {
    timeZone(city);
  }
};

async function timeZone(city) {
  await fetch(`http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/${city}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      //console.log(json);
      setData(json);
    });
}

useEffect(() => {
  timeZone();
}, []);

let mystr = JSON.stringify(data.datetime);

//console.log("city typed  =  "+city);

const cityToCodeMatcher = (city) => {
  let code;
  if (city === "Kolkata") code = "IN";
  else if (city === "Almaty") code = "KZ";
  else if (city === "Amman") code = "JO";
  else if (city === "Ashgabat") code = "TM";
  else if (city === "Baghdad") code = "IQ";
  else if (city === "Baku") code = "AZ";
  else if (city === "Bangkok") code = "TH";
  else if (city === "Beirut") code = "LB";
  else if (city === "Bishkek") code = "KG";
  else if (city === "Brunei") code = "BN";
  else if (city === "Kabul") code = "AF";
  else if (city === "Kathmandu") code = "NP";
  else if (city === "Kuala_Lumpur") code = "MY";
  else if (city === "Pyongyang") code = "KP";
  else if (city === "Manila") code = "PH";
  else if (city === "Riyadh") code = "SA";
  else if (city === "Sanghai") code = "CN";
  else if (city === "Seoul") code = "KR";
  else if (city === "Singapore") code = "SG";
  else if (city === "Taipei") code = "TW";
  else if (city === "Tashkent") code = "UZ";
  else if (city === "Tbilisi") code = "GE";
  else if (city === "Tehran") code = "IR";
  else if (city === "Thimphu") code = "BT";
  else if (city === "Tokyo") code = "JP";
  else if (city === "Ulaanbaatar") code = "MN";
  else if (city === "Yerevan") code = "AM";
  else code = "IN";
  return code;
};

const readySRC = (city) => {
  let temp = "https://www.countryflags.io/".concat(cityToCodeMatcher(city));
  return temp.concat("/shiny/64.png");
};

return (
  <>
    <div style={{ textAlign: "center", padding: "5%", fontSize: "120%" }}>
      <div>
        <label style={{ fontSize: "30px" }}>
          Type Asian City Here..
          <br />
          <input
            type="text"
            style={{ margin: "1%", fontSize: "20px" }}
            placeholder=" Type city here.."
           onChange={(event) => setCity(event.target.value)}
          />
          <br />
          <button onClick={() => handleClick()} style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}>
            Get Current DateTime
          </button>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div style={{padding:'2%'}}>
        Date: {mystr?.slice(1, 11)} <br />
        Time: {mystr?.slice(12, 20)} <br />
        Timezone: {data.timezone}
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src={readySRC(city)} alt="Country flag" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </>
 );  
 };
  export default TimeZoneComponent;
```

I am getting some error:

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://613c3d6616b9dee9895f96c9--adoring-einstein-8cdfd1.netlify.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/undefined'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error right when you launch the site. Your local was http and your production is https but the API URL you have is http.

```
await fetch(`http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/${city}`)
```

make it https.

> Mixed content occurs when HTML on a website loads over a secure HTTPS
> connection (thanks to a recently installed SSL certificate) but other
> content, such as images, video content, stylesheets, and scripts,
> continue to load over an insecure HTTP connection. This results in
> some web content loading securely and some web content loading
> insecurely.

[image]